# How to retrieve two results from SQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql-server

I am using PHP server with SQL Database using CPanel.

I am retrieving values (numbers) from the database using SQL queries and pass them to a separate javascript file.
In order to achieve that, I first created a query on a separate PHP file which gets the information:

File Name: SQLamountofusers.php

```
<?php
$query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT( * ) as c
FROM  `applications` 
JOIN  `users` ON ( users.id = applications.id_m ) 
WHERE  `cdate` > CURRENT_DATE -30"); 

$result = mysql_query($query);

$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo json_encode($res[c]);

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

The echoed result is then passed to a JS file using AJAX:

File Name: canvas.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(usersreport).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'js/SQLamountofusers.php',
            data: 'id=usersreport',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {

            var num = Number(result);

            { label: "Active",  y: num},
            { label: "Inactive",  y: 0  },

    });
});
```

Now this is what I want to achieve but don't know how:

I want to pass to the canvas.js file two values, one is the active users (which requires one query from the DB, which is already written above) and the other is the inactive users (which requires another query) - So how can I get two results into the JS file?

Should I create another separate PHP file with the other query or is there another way to achieve it?

Comment: I am not certain I understand what you are asking, but my best guess is that you want to update your SQL to do a GROUP BY and return the count of each group.  Alternatively, you can do two queries in your php to get both results individually or perhaps even a single query with a UNION.

Comment: You can also make an array that would include results of two separate queries if needed.  Note that `$res[c]` is not valid PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting your query to something like:

```
<?php
$query = sprintf("SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(cdate > CURRENT_DATE - 30, users.id, NULL)) AS c,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(cdate <= CURRENT_DATE - 30, users.id, NULL)) AS d
FROM applications
    JOIN users ON users.id = applications.id_m");

$result = mysql_query($query);

$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo json_encode($res);

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Then you can adjust your canvas.js to pull the result as

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(usersreport).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'js/SQLamountofusers.php',
            data: 'id=usersreport',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {

            var num = Number(result.c);
            var num2 = Number(result.d);

           { label: "Active",  y: num},
           { label: "Inactive",  y: num2 },

     });
});
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this code, just offering this as a potential solution you may try.

Comment: Your SQL query is working well and also the rest of the code, thank you very much I though this could achieve in one SQL query but I wasn't sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

File Name: SQLamountofusers.php

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT( * ) as c
FROM  `applications` 
JOIN  `users` ON ( users.id = applications.id_m ) 
WHERE  `cdate` > CURRENT_DATE -30"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);

$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$data = array('active' => $res['c']);

$query2 = "SELECT ...";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$res2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
$data['inactive'] = $res2['c']);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

File Name: canvas.js

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(usersreport).click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'js/SQLamountofusers.php',
            data: 'id=usersreport',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {

            { label: "Active",  y: result.active},
            { label: "Inactive",  y: result.inactive},

    });
});
```

Just replace second sql query with the one you need.

EDIT: Basically you can pass through json arrays and objects. So you can easily pass as many numbers as you want. Prepare php array with values you need, then json_encode() it and you will get an object or array with values on js side.
If you encode php array without keys like $arr = array(1,2,3); you will get array on js side. You can reference it as a[0], a[1] etc.
If you encode associative php array, i.e. with keys like $arr = array('k1'=>1, 'k2'=>2); you will get an object on js side. And reference it as o.k1, o.k2 etc.

Comment: Very elegant solution, unfortunately I didn't manage to implement it. can't even debug it as there was not any error in the console .
Anyway thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Try: 

`$query = "SELECT COUNT( * ) as c
FROM  applications 
JOIN  users ON ( users.id = applications.id_m ) 
WHERE  cdate > CURRENT_DATE -30";`

Without sprintf();